# Device management not showing up on iOS 9.2.1

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

[image]

I truly don't know where to find this when I look it up under the search for settings it brings me to the general settings then leaves me there. I've tried to restart my iPhone but nothing seems to work and I've looked up numerous ways to try and fix it but I can seem to do it.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: i am looking for the profiles and device management settings tab

Comment: Settings-General-Profiles & device Management. You'd see this option when you have at least one MDM, configuration or provisioning profile.

Comment: @Kodie Vin is correct. The section won't appear until you actually install a profile.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a profile installed on your phone yet. Once you do, it will appear

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions